# Python: Get data through Thingspeak

Tags: python, sql, arduino

I want to capture the sensor data through thingspeak.
I used the url provided with the api key in the browser:

`http://api.thingspeak.com/update?key=MYKEY&field1=25&field2=75`

I expect it will return field1 and field2, but the result below shows only the value of field1.

```
"channel":{
    "id":202242,
    "name":"DHT11",
    "latitude":"0.0",
    "longitude":"0.0",
    "field1":"Temperature ( degC ) 1",
    "field2":"Humidity ( % )",
    "created_at":"2016-12-11T17:16:21Z",
    "updated_at":"2016-12-11T18:12:00Z",
    "last_entry_id":12
},

"feeds":[
    {
        "created_at":"2016-12-11T18:12:00Z",
        "entry_id":12,
        "field1":25
    }
]
```

What step have I missed?

Comment: share link to api doc please.

Comment: try this approach and see if it works: https://gist.github.com/vi3k6i5/5099e4fceeb4bff5eb0b35f7d5b7e298

Comment: try this: https://gist.github.com/vi3k6i5/f85b929d9680fca9ad4f6d8d694a0ab4  sorry about the experiments.

Comment: it said = behind the "api_key" is invalid syntax

Comment: sorry man, = is not valid for dictionary try this https://gist.github.com/vi3k6i5/be04f8b68169f5fcf3b39bdc80a8caf7 simply replace = with :

Comment: dude {"api_key":"XXAA"}

Comment: thx it can work but my missing 'field2' still exit

Comment: see your channel configuration and make sure you have enabled 2 fields. If it still doesn't work then it might be a bug on API end. Try reporting.

Comment: ok...i make sure i have two fields...thx

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:
Here you make request using APIs. You will find various API requests [here](http://here).

```
import urllib2
import json
import time


READ_API_KEY='   '
CHANNEL_ID= '    '


while True:
    TS = urllib2.urlopen("http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/%s/feeds/last.json?api_key=%s" \
                       % (CHANNEL_ID,READ_API_KEY))

    response = TS.read()
    data=json.loads(response)


    a = data['created_at']
    b = data['field1']
    c = data['field2']
    d = data['field3']
    print a + "    " + b + "    " + c + "    " + d
    time.sleep(5)   

    TS.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you add some additional text describing what this approach really means? Maybe take a look at the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) in order to get ideas for how to better post answers.